# Silverstripe Custom Validator on Uploadfield

Tags: silverstripe

I am using foresight.js to load hi-res images for retina devices. Foresight attempts to replace lo-res images with 2x-pixel density images. Since foresight attempts to replace lo-res images before the page has rendered, it is not possible for me to use the GD image resizing methods in the template for my resized images. So, I am allowing the SS 3.1 cms user to upload one large image and having the system re-size it after upload - leaving a 1x and 2x image in the assets folder.

My question is how can I set a custom validation error message if the cms user does not upload a large enough image?

Here is the code that resizes the image on upload.

```
class ResampledImage extends Image {
    static $default_lores_x = 250;
    static $default_lores_y = 250;
    static $default_hires_x = 500;
    static $default_hires_y = 500;
    static $default_assets_dir = 'Uploads';
    static $hires_flag = '2x';

    function getLoResX() {
        return ( static::$lores_x ) ? static::$lores_x : self::$default_lores_x;    
    }

    function getLoResY() {
        return ( static::$lores_y ) ? static::$lores_y : self::$default_lores_y;
    }

    function getHiResX() {
        return ( static::$hires_x ) ? static::$hires_x : self::$default_hires_x;
    }

    function getHiResY() {
        return ( static::$hires_y ) ? static::$hires_y : self::$default_hires_y;
    }

    function getAssetsDir() {
        return ( static::$assets_dir ) ? static::$assets_dir : self::$default_assets_dir;
    }

    function onAfterUpload() {
        $this->createResampledImages();
    }

    function onAfterWrite() {
        $this->createResampledImages();
    }

    function createResampledImages() {
        $extension = strtolower($this->getExtension());
        if( $this->getHeight() >= $this->getHiResX() || $this->getWidth() >= $this->getHiResY() ) {
        $original = $this->getFullPath();
        $resampled = $original. '.tmp.'. $extension;    

        $orig_title = $this->getTitle();
        $path_to_hires = Director::baseFolder() . '/' . ASSETS_DIR . '/' . $this->getAssetsDir();
        $hires =  $path_to_hires . '/' . $orig_title . self::$hires_flag . '.' . $extension;

        $gd_lg = new GD($original);
        $gd_sm = new GD($original);

        if ( $gd_lg->hasImageResource() ) {
            $gd_lg = $gd_lg->resizeRatio($this->getHiResX(), $this->getHiResY());

            if ( $gd_lg ) 
                $gd_lg->writeTo($hires);
        }

        if($gd_sm->hasImageResource()) {
            $gd_sm = $gd_sm->resizeRatio($this->getLoResX(), $this->getLoResY());

            if($gd_sm) {
                $gd_sm->writeTo($resampled);
                unlink($original);
                rename($resampled, $original);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at UploadField::setFileEditValidator() it appears that I can designate a method on my extended Image class to use as a Validator so that I can check for $this->getWidth() and $this->getHeight() and return an error if they are not large enough.

Is this possible?

I tried adding the following method to ResampledImage, but this was unsuccessful:

```
function MyValidator() {
    $valid = true;

    if ( $this->getHeight() < $this->getHiResX() || $this->getWidth() < $this->getHiResY() ) {
        $this->validationError("Thumbnail",'Please upload a larger image');
        $valid = false;
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

Comment: /threadnecro - some of your static:: declarations look to be missing?

Comment: I abandoned using Foresight and having to resize on upload. Foresight doesn't seem to play well with grabbing images resized using the SS Image methods - hence the messiness above. I am using the heyday silverstripe responsive images extension instead and using the custom Upload Validator method described below with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `fileEditValidator` is acutally used after the image has been uploaded and is for the `EditForm` when displayed/edited.

Seems that what you are looking for is validate the `Upload`. You can set a custom `Upload_Validator` with `setValidator($validator)` on your `UploadField`.

So what I would try is create a custom validator class (maybe named CustomUploadValidator) that extends `Upload_Validator` (source can be found in the Upload.php file in the framework). So, something along those lines:

```
$myValidator = new CustomUploadValidator();
$uploadField->setValidator($myValidator);
```

In your custom validator class maybe create a method `isImageLargeEnough()` which you would call in the `validate()` method:

```
public function validate() {

    if(!$this->isImageLargeEnough()) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Image size is not large enough';
        return false;
    }

    return parent::validate();
}
```

In your `isImageLargeEnough()` you can access the uploaded image through `$this->tmpFile`. So maybe do something like:

```
public function isImageLargeEnough()
{
    $imageSize = getimagesize( $this->tmpFile["tmp_name"] );
    if ($imageSize !== false)
    {
        if ( $imageSize[0] < 500 || $imageSize[1] < 500 )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }       
    return true;
}
```

Here the min width/height are hard coded to 500, but you can probably implement a `setMinImageSizes` method that stores those on a variable in your custom validator class. which could be called like `$uploadField->getValidator()->setMinImageSize(543, 876);`

None of this is actually tested, but hopefully it can give you some pointers on what to look for.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation. I did need to assign parent::validate() to a variable and return the variable from my validate method to get it working for me, but great answer!

Comment: cool, glad it worked. updated the answer fixing `validate()` to also return its parent, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Colymba, note that I also needed to check if getimagesize returned false within the isImageLargeEnough method before checking image size. SS appears to run the image through the validate method on upload and write and getimagesize was returning false during write validation.

Comment: Colymba, do you know how I would return the custom error message to the template? Upon validation failure, the EditForm is only showing a generic 'Forbidden' error. When I check the Network Tab, the server is returning the proper message `[{"error":"Please upload a larger image"}]` - it's just not being passed to the Uploadfield template.

Comment: not sure... I usually seen the 'Forbidden' message when trying to access an action which is not explicitly defined in a `allowed_actions`. Can you post a link to a Gist with your code in, so I can try and test it on my side?

Comment: Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/toddvalentine/6281872. Contains everything you should need to set this up. It does seem like I will need to figure out how SS passes errors to the js templates.

Comment: thx for the code, did some digging and it seems to be a SilverStripe bug. Basically if the Upload/Validation returns any error the server respond with 403 Forbidden code. A quick fix is to comment out line 1226 of UploadField.php `if(!empty($return['error'])) $response->setStatusCode(403);`. This will need more work and probably a PR though...

Comment: Pull Request submitted if you want to track when this is fixed https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/2344

Comment: This solution is valid for v. 4.x too. Just change ```tmpFile["tmp_name"]``` into ```tmpFile["name"]```