# Silverstripe 3 set minimum width and minimum height for image uploads memberprofil module

Tags: image, validation, size, silverstripe

I'm looking for a solution to implement a validation to set minimum height and minimum width for image uploads. I think the Framework doesn't offer these functionalities by default.

```
Example : Allowed image upload minimum width: 500px and minimum height: 500px
```

There is my code extending Member Dataobject :

member_extension.php

```
require_once 'ImageUpload_Validator.php';

class MemberExtension extends DataExtension {

  private static $has_one = array(
    'ImageMembre' => 'Image'
  );

  public function updateMemberFormFields(FieldList $fields) {

        //setup the new validator

        $validator = new ImageUpload_Validator();
        $validator->setMinDimensions(500,500);
        $validator->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
        //$validator->setAllowedMaxFileSize(array('*' => 4194304));



        $fields->push( $Upload = new UploadField('ImageMembre', 'Image membre'));

            $Upload->setValidator($validator);

  }

    function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) { 

       // $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $uploadfield = new UploadField('ImageMembre','Image Membre');

        //setup the new validator

        $validator = new ImageUpload_Validator();
        $validator->setMinDimensions(500,500);
        $validator->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
        //$validator->setAllowedMaxFileSize(array('*' => 4194304));


        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',$uploadfield);
            $uploadfield->setValidator($validator);

        return $fields;
    }
```

After save, It return me the error : Minimum image size is 500px x 500px , but my image have alot more resolution.

I think there are an error in the script bellow :

ImageUpload_Validator.php

```
class ImageUpload_Validator extends Upload_Validator{
    public $minwidth;
    public $minheight;
    public function setMinDimensions($width,$height){
        if(is_numeric($width) && intval($width)>=0)
            $this->minwidth=intval($width);
        else
            user_error('Invalid minimum width, value must be numeric and at least 0',E_USER_ERROR);
        if(is_numeric($height) && intval($height)>=0)
            $this->minheight=intval($height);
        else
            user_error('Invalid minimum height, value must be numeric and at least 0',E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    public function isValidDimensions() {
        //if we cannot determine the image size return false
        if(!$dims = getimagesize($this->tmpFile['tmp_name']))
            return false;
        if(($this->minheight && $dims[1]<=$this->minheight) || ($this->minwidth && $dims[0]<=$this->minwidth))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public function validate(){
        if(!isset($this->tmpFile['name']) || empty($this->tmpFile['name']))
            return true;
        if(!$this->isValidDimensions()){
            $this->errors[]=sprintf('Minimum image size is %s x %s ', $this->minwidth?$this->minwidth.'px':'(ANY)',$this->minheight?$this->minheight.'px':'(ANY)');
            return false;
        }
        return parent::validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silverstripe Custom Validator on Uploadfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242663/silverstripe-custom-validator-on-uploadfield)

Comment: Hi wmk, not entire duplicate... I'm refering to the memberprofil module that return me error 500 when I'm trying to include my code into updateMemberFormFields. My custom validation in the CMS works fine. There is the link that I use for my custom validation : [link](https://gist.github.com/opalfroot/14524bf50f9657ef7d21)

Comment: So you already have the validation running and want to add it to MemberProfilePage?

Comment: Yes, but it return me error 500 when i'm trying to add it into updateMemberFormFields function...

Comment: Can you share some code and/or dig for the error in error logs?

Comment: There is my modified question with some codes. I'm looking how can I export logs right now.

Comment: I'm trying to get logs with : `SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogFileWriter('silverstripe.log'), SS_Log::WARN, '>');` and no file are created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94547/discussion-between-wmk-and-stephane-guevremont).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have consulted the question and anwser on the link a top telling my question is duplicate... [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242663/silverstripe-custom-validator-on-uploadfield).
And I realise some error in my script and I have reedit it with some new coding. I have replace the validate function with other post code and it works!

```
class ImageUpload_Validator extends Upload_Validator{
    public $minwidth;
    public $minheight;
    public function setMinDimensions($width,$height){
        if(is_numeric($width) && intval($width)>=0)
            $this->minwidth=intval($width);
        else
            user_error('Invalid minimum width, value must be numeric and at least 0',E_USER_ERROR);
        if(is_numeric($height) && intval($height)>=0)
            $this->minheight=intval($height);
        else
            user_error('Invalid minimum height, value must be numeric and at least 0',E_USER_ERROR);
    }


    public function isImageLargeEnough()
    {
        $imageSize = getimagesize( $this->tmpFile["tmp_name"] );
        if ($imageSize !== false)
        {
            if ( $imageSize[0] < $this->minwidth || $imageSize[1] < $this->minheight )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }       
        return true;
    }

    public function validate() {

        if(!$this->isImageLargeEnough()) {
            //$this->errors[] = 'Image size is not large enough';
         $this->errors[]=sprintf('Minimum image size is %s x %s ', $this->minwidth?$this->minwidth.'px':'(ANY)',$this->minheight?$this->minheight.'px':'(ANY)');
return false;
        }

    return parent::validate();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your updateMemberFormFields you have to switch some lines:

```
    $Upload->setValidator($validator);
    $fields->push( $Upload = new UploadField('ImageMembre', 'Image membre'));
```

should be

```
    $fields->push( $Upload = new UploadField('ImageMembre', 'Image membre'));
    $Upload->setValidator($validator);
```

Otherwise you assign something to a undefined object...

Comment: Oups i have respond too fast! When I'm click save, it return validation error from cms and display min width and height problem... Can you help again? Thanks!